# C++ array of objects initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, object, initialization

I have to write the rest of code to make this work:

```
int main()
{
    Pair p[2] = {{7,21}};
    cout<< p[0] <<" , "<< p[1] <<endl;
    double d[2] = { p[0], p[1] };
    cout<< "d = " << d[0] <<" , "<< d[1] <<endl;
}
```

I've made some attempts but didn't really come up with anything that makes sense.

output should be

```
7 , 21
d = 7 , 21
```

This is from my c++ exam on second year, anyone knows how?

Comment: You have an array of *two* `Pair` objects, you explicitly initialize the first element in the array (`p[0]`) with `{7, 21}`. The second element (`p[1]`) is implicitly initialized to "zero" (exactly what happens depends on the `Pair` class or structure and what (possible) constructors it has and what they do).

Comment: Oh and you should probably take some to to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, you show us the expected output, but what is the *actual* output?

Comment: There is no actual output because it's not finished yet... That's what I have to do.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you convert from a *pair* of numbers to a single floating point (`double`)?

Comment: Please turn up the warnings setting of your compiler to maximum.

Comment: The fundamental operation of `double d[2] = ` can be expressed as `double d = Pair(7,21);`, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective (which you didn't state in your post), is to design `Pair` class to make the program work, your class will need the following:

1. Constructor that takes 2 arguments.
2. Constructor that takes 0 arguments.
3. Overloading `operator<<` to work with streams.
4. Overloading `operator double` to return a `double` value from a
   `Pair`.

Item 4 may be difficult because there are an infinite number of equations that return a `double` given 2 integers.  You'll need more information or create some kind of function like this:

```
  double operator double () { return first * 4 + second;}
```

**Edit 1:**
You may also need to overload `operator[]`.  The `Pair` class looks like an array of integers.